# Redirect script output to log file OR terminal by request

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script that I want by default to output everything into a log file.  However, I also want the ability to output it to the calling terminal by request (e.g. parameter) INSTEAD of the log file (so `tee` is out I believe).  Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

It would be nice if the parameter could be a custom log file OR a reference to a calling terminal.

I'm thinking along the lines of this: (pseudo-code)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $1 ]; then
    OUT="default.log"
else
    OUT=$1
fi

#then do this to every call in the script
commands [param] [param] >> ${OUT}
```

I guess more of what I am asking is, is there an easy way to reference the current terminal for output to?  So I could do `./script.sh`, `./script.sh custom.log` or `script.sh TERMINAL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `/dev/stdout` as a filename would do what you want.

Comment: Ahh, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Been a while since I've done bash scripting. (edit: can't accept the answer for 7 minutes)

Comment: Be advised that `/dev/stdout` is not in the Single UNIX Specification, Version 3.  A more portable choice would be `/dev/tty`, which is in the Standard.

Answer (score 3):

I might go with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 != --stdout ]]; then
    exec >> "${1:-default.log}"
fi

commands [param] [param]
```

Result: If the user passes `--stdout` then output goes to stdout, otherwise it goes to a log file. The user can pass the log file name on the command-line, and if they don't specify one it defaults to `default.log`.

The `exec` part is nice because it redirects all future output from your script. It saves you from having to add `>> ${OUT}` to every single command.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for this.  So many neat little things in bash that are great to use but hard to find.

Comment: This is much nicer, but would you not need to add `--stdout` to the arguments on the exec line?

Comment: @grddev: No that's just an argument to the script. By not redirecting the output it will go to `stdout` if the script is passed `--stdout`. If it's not then the `exec` will send it to a named file or to `default.log` if a name is not supplied.

Comment: @Dennis: Ah, I wasn't aware that `exec` doesn't actually do (the C function) `exec` when you do not supply any arguments, but instead just redirects the inputs/outputs of the running instance.